# how change zend framework default application title error page?

Tags: zend-framework, error-handling

I threw exception error on zend framework 1.12 project and he gave me response page with title "Zend Framework Default Application".

how can i change the title page? 
thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you need to modify is in `application/controllers/ErrorController.php` and the associated view-script `application/views/scripts/error/error.phtml`.

Go nuts! ;-)

Comment: haha.. thank you Sir!.. since my project use modular structure and support themes, now i want to make it available to all my modules.

Comment: Aaah, when I want to use a common error handler across all modules, I usually pull it out into something like `App_Controller_Action_Error extends Zend_Controller_Action` stored  in `library/App/Controller/Action/Error.php`. Then, in a module `mymodule`, I define an empty class `Mymodule_ErrorController extends App_Controller_Action_Error` in `application/modules/mymodule/controllers/ErrorController.php`. Remember to add `autoloadernamespaces[] = "App_"` to `application/configs/application.ini`.

Comment: thanks for reply... 
I create plugin that render path_theme/error.phtml. controller error handler also a plugin too.. so I unregister it and register my own (in bootstrap)